# I have difficulty using map function in python

Tags: python, map-function

I am very new to python.
I researched about my problem but couldn't get the excepted answer.
What I don't understand here is how is `myfunc` being called as it has no parameters like `myfunc()` and how is argument  `(n)` taking two arguments(apple and banana)?

```
    def myfunc(n):
        return len(n)

    x = list(map(myfunc,('apple', 'banana')))
    print(x)
   
    output:
    [5,6]
```

Comment: It's not taking two arguments. You're calling `myfunc` first with `'apple'`, and then calling it again with `'banana'`.

Comment: It doesn't take two arguments, but one. Once the argument is `apple` (then the returned length is 5, as it has five letters) and then the argument is `banana`, with the lenght 6.
What you might have not known that strings behave like collections (of characters) in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map(fun, iterable)` applies the `fun` function to each element in the iterable (e.g. a list) and returns the each of the output in a list.

The reason why the function `myfunc` has no argument is that you should see it just as an argument of the `map` function.

Try to think of map, for your example, like this:

`[5, 6] = [myfunc('apple'), myfunc('banana')]`

internally, the `map` function is doing something like:

```
def map(myfunc, iterable):
    returns = []
    for i in iterable:
        returns.append(myfunc(i))
    return returns
```

Answer (score 2):

Map doesn't actually take a function, it takes the reference to a function. References are passed without the parentheses and hence you can't supply arguments manually, map does that for you. For eg.
If we want to convert anything to integer, we'll use

`int(50.65)`

But map takes only the reference to function.

`map(int, input().split())`